# How do I convert the following "poly" output to a function useable in Excel?

Tags: r, lm, polynomials

I carried out a linear regression in R using the following code:

```
model <- lm(z~poly(x3,x4, degree=2,raw=TRUE), MyData)
```

The output is something like this:

```
(Intercept)
0.1742518
poly(x3, x4, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)2.0
-1.130082
poly(x3, x4, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.1
-17.35482
...
```

Is there some way to automatically convert the above code to this?

```
z ~ 0.1742518-1.130082*x3^2-17.35482*x3*x4
```

Keeping in mind that although we have two variables here (x3,x4), there might be more variables, and also the number of terms generated by polynomial can be quite large, rendering the manual creation of such formulas tedious.

Comment: Does your `lm` only have the `poly` for 2 vars? and do you also have + X1 etc? aka `lm(z ~ poly(x3, x4) + x1 + x2, mydata)` or also `lm(z ~ poly(x3, x4, x5, ....) + x1 + x2, mydata)`

Comment: @phiver - It's only inside poly. In fact, I didn't know I could have a combination with both within poly and outside it. Something to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked for flexibility and I've kind of provided it here. The main challenge is in processing the coefficient names produced by `poly` to make them pretty for a person. Note, the solution I provide here assumes *every* term in your model is wrapped in `poly` except for the intercept.

```
MyData = data.frame(x3=runif(100),x4=runif(100))
MyData$z = 0.17 -1.13*MyData$x3^2-17.35*MyData$x3*MyData$x4+rnorm(100)

model <- lm(z~poly(x3,x4, degree=2,raw=TRUE), MyData)
summary(model)$coef
```

Your question didn't include a reproducible sample, so I created one.  The function below is designed to process the poly coefficient name and return a nice `x3`, `x4` type name instead.

```
processPolyNames = function(coef){
  members = strsplit(mgsub::mgsub(coef,c("poly\\(",", degre.*"),c("","")),", ")[[1]]
  degree = as.numeric(strsplit(strsplit(coef,")")[[1]][2],"\\.")[[1]])
  coef_out = ""
  for(d in seq_along(degree)){
    if(degree[d] == 0) next
    if(degree[d] == 1){
      if(coef_out == ""){
        coef_out = members[d]
      } else {
        coef_out = paste0(coef_out,"*",members[d])
      }
    } else {
      if(coef_out == ""){
        coef_out = paste0(members[d],"^",degree[d])
      } else {
        coef_out = paste0(coef_out,"*",members[d],"^",degree[d])
      }
    }
  }
  return(coef_out)
}
```

Now we extract the coefficients of the model - if you only want to include the significant effects, you could filter `coefs`. I then `lapply` the function I wrote to the ugly names to get pretty names.

```
coefs = summary(model)$coef[,1]
prettyNames = lapply(names(coefs)[-1],processPolyNames)
unlist(prettyNames)
#> [1] "x3"    "x3^2"  "x4"    "x3*x4" "x4^2"
```

Now we need to make a pretty Model. This is just a for loop. Starting with the intercept we then just build out the model (rounding the coefficients to 7 significant digits.

```
prettyModel = ""
for(i in seq_along(coefs)){
  if(i == 1){
    prettyModel = paste0(prettyModel,round(coefs[i],7))
  } else {
    prettyModel = paste0(prettyModel,ifelse(coefs[i] >= 0,"+",""),round(coefs[i],7),"*",prettyNames[[i-1]])
  }
}

prettyModel
#> [1] "0.1169037+1.8662887*x3-3.0333651*x3^2-1.3031079*x4-17.1641031*x3*x4+1.5259313*x4^2"
```

That model could then be `mgsub`'d to replace the variables with the Excel cell references as desired.

Comment: Thank you, I did implement something very similar to what you wrote. But the problem is that the results are not good on my test data. The improved accuracy over the linear regression on training data is outweighed by a terrible `R^2` coefficient on test data. (I'm working on bridge pier scour data)

Answer (score 0):

For the above example with 2 variables, the solution could be:

```
x3 <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
x4 <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
y <- x3*3 + 3* x3 * x4
model <- lm(y ~ poly(x3, x4, degree=2, raw=TRUE))

paste( "z ~",unname(model$coefficients)[1], "-", unname(model$coefficients)[2], 
       "* x3 ^ 2 -", unname(model$coefficients)[3], "* x3 * x4" )
##"z ~ -1.91152113238255e-12 - 5.4307136268434e-14 * x3 ^ 2 - 1.04899226410413e-14 * x3 * x4"
```

However if you want to use it in more general way (handling different number of arguments to the formula etc.), then you can process various components that are in your `model`:

```
str(model)
List of 12
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:6] -1.91e-12 5.43e-14 1.05e-14 3.00 3.00 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "(Intercept)" "poly(trt, ctl, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0" "poly(trt, ctl, degree = 2, raw = TRUE
...
```

The above is just a partial output, but you can find the members of the list, that would contain the formula itself and all variables that were used there and then write the function that would loop through each variable and add the coefficient to it just like in the example above.

Comment: I found a solution by using two for loops, first one for iterating over each poly output and extracting substrings like `(x3, x4), (2.0)`, then another loop to generate the power functions `x3^2*x4^0`, and it works if I use more than two variables. But your method is much more compact and elegant.